# Number "in range" is Reporting as "not in range" on First Attempt

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I am writing a script in Powershell to allow an admin and myself to perform a couple of basic Active Directory tasks without having to open ADUC and fiddle through menus. I have numbers 1-4 to be able to be selected, and responses allowed should be`less than 1` or `greater than/equal to 5` (I've tried `greater than 4` as well).

```
$Response =  Read-Host "Number"
[int]$Response = 0
while ($Response -lt 1 -or $Response -ge 5)
    {
     $Response = Read-Host "Please enter a number within range"
    }
    Switch ($Response)
    {
```

Responses "2" and "3" are accepted and the script runs properly; however, Responses "1" and "4" are denied with the Read-Host `Please enter a number within range`. **When they are entered again at the prompt, it works correctly:**

```
What would you like to do today?
1. Reset a user's password
2. Enable a user account
3. Disable a user account
4. Unlock a user
   Number: 4
Please enter a number within range.: 4
   Who needs to be unlocked?:
```

I've very confused as to why the same snippet of code denies, and then allows the same response. If needed, the rest of my code is just the switches, and thanks for any input you may have.

```
1
 {}
2
 {}
3
 {}
4
 {}
```

Comment: Why not use an if qualifier before starting the switch statement? That way you can loop back if incorrect input is done, or follow it through if its correct?

Comment: `[int]$Response = 0` First response always zero.

Comment: PetSerAl is stating that your first two lines are backwards. Really could just be `[int]$Response =  Read-Host "Number"`. As an aside you should look into [Choices](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which does most of this work for you.

Comment: @Matt I have never seen `Choices` before, that is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

> "`[int]$Response = 0` First response always zero."
> - PetSerAl
>
> "PetSerAl is stating that your first two lines are backwards. Really could just be `[int]$Response = Read-Host "Number"`. As an aside you should look into Choices which does most of this work for you." 
> - Matt

After taking out the following line, the code works perfectly. I'm not sure how this affects the input, but it solved it. Thanks!

Updated Code: 
    `$Response =  Read-Host "Number"
    while ($Response -lt 1 -or $Response -ge 5)`